# Mathematical units in gt table with Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, gt

I have this `dataframe`:

```
df = data.frame(a = c("$B_{a}$", "$m^{a}$"))
```

When I make a table using `kable` in `Rmarkdown` like so:

```
df %>% knitr::kable()
```

and `knit` it to a `pdf_document`, I get this:

[image]

which is what I expected.

Now, I want to reproduce the same table, but using the package `gt`. When I do:

```
library(gt)
df %>% gt()
```

I get this:

[image]

What else do I have to do that so that `gt` table "understands" these are mathematical notations?

Comment: You may need `sup` for `gt` i.e. something like `df1 <- data.frame(a = "B<sup>a</sup>");
> df1 %>% gt() %>% fmt_markdown(columns = everything())`

Comment: @akrun as I do not know `html` I would not prefer doing something like this. Do you think this is the only way?

Comment: I think the `fmt_markdown` follow the markdown syntax.  Do you want to convert the original data syntax into one I showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<sub></sub>` and `<sup></sup>` works with `gt`.  One option is to replace the characters in the original dataset column with html syntax using `str_remove/str_replace` from `stringr`

```
library(gt)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(a = str_remove_all(a, "[{}$]") %>% 
         str_replace_all( c('(.)_(.)', "(.)\\^(.)"),
           c("\\1<sub>\\2</sub>", "\\1<sup>\\2</sup>"))) %>%
     gt() %>%
     fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
```

-output

[image]

Comment: This does work for the over-simplified example I showed, but in reality, I have many columns with many values (3-4 A4 pages) with different types of **very** complicated physical units that does not necessarily look like this example I showed.

Comment: @bird Ok, If you have multiple columns, use `mutate(across(yourcolumns, .` and do the transform for those selected columns.   I showed a method to convert from your original showed example to the format that `gt` can work

Comment: @bird Otherwise, if you have lots of changes, then may be have to rewrite it with the html tags

Comment: I agree that your suggested method works for this specific problem I posted, but I feel like with this method I have to learn `html` and do a lot of different `html` tagging to change each of the unit separately (as they do not follow the same pattern)

Comment: @bird what would be your expected solution for this.  Is the question aimed for converting the kable code automatically or parse in the current version in gt

Comment: I just want to switch to `gt` (from `knitr::kable`) for making tables as I find it much more flexible and also it offers a lot more features for scientific writing etc.